# Trying to return the average from 3 number using a function (JS)

Tags: javascript, function, average

I'm just playing with JS and trying to learn it.

I am trying to determine the average of three numbers; for that, I have defined a function with three parameters and declared parameter values.

But the function isn't returning the average, but when I run console.log, it shows the average.

```
function make_avg(num1, num2, num3) {
  var total = num1 + num2 + num3;
  var average = total / 3;
  return average;
}
make_avg(15, 20, 25);
```

I have tried with this code but am unable to return the average. Can you tell me the issues with my code and the possible solution?

Comment: `const avg = make_avg(15, 20, 25); console.log(avg)`

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values)

Comment: You ARE returning the average. Why you think you are not? Can you add some info where you are testing this? In browser's console?

Comment: No im tying in vs code, here you can check the screenshot https://prnt.sc/6xSGh_0J1p2V

Comment: You're calling the function, but not doing anything with its returned value. You have to tell the console or whatever to display it.

Comment: Ah, I got it, so it won't return the value in the terminal unless I console.log it, right?

Comment: @TakibulIslamFuad your function is being called, but the return value is not being printed to the console. you can use `console.log(make_avg(15, 20, 25))` to print the result of the function call to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return it, if you want to use that value, you should assign the returned value to a variable.

```
const num = make_avg(15, 20, 25)
// num will be equal to 20
```

It actually depends on what you are rerturning and how you are using it. For example if you are returning a boolean value (true/false), you can put it in a conditional statement without assigning it to a variable. E.g:

```
function isString(arg){
  return typeof arg === 'string'
}

// you can then say:

if(isString('hello world')){
  console.log("yes, it is a string") // because the function will return true, this block will execute
}
```

**EXTRAS**

Your function is kinda limited to only finding the average of three numbers. You can scale this up by instead passing an array of numbers, and then changing your function to add the numbers (using .reduce on the array) and then divide the sum by the length of the array (which is the number of digits). This can find the average of any amount. NOTE: I will give the code to do this next. You can try it out yourself before checking the code, or maybe check it out if you get stuck.

**MODIFIED AVERAGE FINDER FUNCTION**

```
  function find_avg(arrOfNums) {
    var total = arrOfNums.reduce((a, b) => {return a + b}, 0)
    var average = total / arrOfNums.length;
    return average;
  }

// let's test it out

  const avg = find_avg([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
  // avg will be 3.5
```

Remember that the function must always take in an array as its arguments
Enjoy your journey into JavaScript. Hope this was helpful :)

Comment: I can't thank you enough for the resources and suggestions you have provided. I'm going to learn these now!!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works. To make it shorter and work with as few or many numbers you want you could do:

```
const makeAvg = (...nums) => nums.reduce((a, c) => a + c) / nums.length;

console.log(makeAvg(15, 20, 25));
```

Read about **spread syntax** (the ... used before nums) here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

And about the array method **reduce** here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

And about **arrow functions** here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: You may want to link to the documentation for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to improve your answer, and maybe explain a little what each one does.

Comment: The OP is starting to learn, it's a style preference to go for functionnal one-liners that may be be too early for a beginner. Personnally I think it's not the best habit, it is less readable and usually adds overhead in performance and memory. Plus it's not what the OP asked, introducing arrow functions when OP cannot return yet will complicate things

Comment: On the other hand map, reduce and other array methods that make programming more functional (doesn't have to be in oneliners) is a *de facto* standard of how you write JS in a modern way. So its the 'style preference' to learn if you want to be employed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Maybe I was expecting e "return " tto show the value in the terminal.

Comment: Arrow functions return what's after the arrow - if they have no program block. So you don't have to write 'return' to return something in this case.

Comment: @TakibulIslamFuad If you REALLY want a return, you can do `const makeAvg = (...nums) => { return nums.reduce((a, c) => a + c) / nums.length; };` which you need if you have more than one line anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good! You can extend your solution to find the average of any count of numbers by utilizing an array

```js
function average(numbers) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (const num of numbers) {
    sum += num
  }

  return sum / numbers.length;
}
console.log(average([1, 2, 3, 4])) // should output 2.5
```

Additionally, you could also utilize the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) if you wanted to avoid creating an array manually:

```js
function average(...numbers) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (const num of numbers) {
    sum += num
  }

  return sum / numbers.length;
}
console.log(average(1, 2, 3, 4)) // should output 2.5
```